# Why are the particles in LiquidFun so bouncy?

Tags: c++, simulation, raspberry-pi4, openframeworks, liquidfun

I’m trying to use LiquidFun/ofxLiquidFun to simulate 2d water. But I’m constantly getting very bouncy particles. It looks like the simulated water is boiling.

I already changed all the settings like step period, iterations, particle size, scale, damping, velocity, particle flags. But adding extra damping or flags which should cancel the bounciness actually makes it worse. Does anyone know how to change this?

The LiquidFun demon on the website looks much better. When there is no movement for a while, the particles actually stop moving. On my C++ version, the particles keep moving/jittering/bouncing. Especially the lower half of a simulated "cup of water". Can it be due to differences in floating point calculations?
https://google.github.io/liquidfun/

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4B 2GB.